# How can I make my JButton flicker at a prescribed frequency using threads in Java?

Tags: multithreading, jbutton

I'm trying to cause a jbutton to flicker at a prescribed frequency, in this case, 40Hz. I've written code inside the loop in the thread to flip the background and forground colors on each pass, thus achieving 1 Hz when the loop has finished two passes. Although I have code that shows each pass is occurring at ~13ms, the button is only visibly flipping background and forground colors a few times per second. I've built a hardware version that flickers at 40Hz and know that that is just below the flicker rate where the human eye sees a blur. This is no where near 40Hz.

My question is why do the results (no. of reps per second) show a loop that is spining at ~13ms per pass as it should, why does the jbutton forground and background colors, set in that same loop, instead change a couple of times per second?

My code is below:

```
// JPanelLiteBrixFlicker.java

package lb.jpanel;

import lb.jpanel.roundedborder.RoundedBorder;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author evan
 */
public class JPanelLiteBrixFlicker extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private boolean bFrameIsOpen = false;

    private final static int iFiftyMSecs = 50;  // time delay while (! bFrameIsOpen)
    
    JButton oJButton = new JButton("+");

    public JPanelLiteBrixFlicker() {
        initComponents();

        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(1, 3);
        setLayout(experimentLayout);

        setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 120));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 120));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 120));
        setSize(new Dimension(150, 120));

        configureButton();

    }

    public void launchThreadInJPanelLiteBrixFlicker() {
        Color cMagenta = new Color(102, 0, 102);
        Color cWhite = new Color(255, 255, 255);

        oJButton.setBackground(cWhite);
        oJButton.setForeground(cMagenta);

        new Thread(new JPanelLiteBrixFlicker.Task("JPanelLiteBrix")) {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Color cMagenta = new Color(102, 0, 102);
                Color cWhite = new Color(255, 255, 255);

// Set iCurrentThreadPriority to normal priority; reset in loop as time per pass varies.

                int iCurrentThreadPriority = Thread.NORM_PRIORITY;
                int iMaxThreadPriority = Thread.MAX_PRIORITY;
                int iMinThreadPriority = Thread.MIN_PRIORITY;

// Time delay to wait for components to become available, it is then used to adjust 
// the speed of the loop dependent on o/s delays.

                boolean bIsIncreasing = false;

                int iAlzheimersFrequency = 12;  // 1 / 80Hz in ms, or 12.5ms, adjusted below

                LinkedList<StatsElement> oLinkedListOfStatsElements = new LinkedList<>();

                long lDelayTimeInMilliSecs = 16;

                long lCurrentTime;
                long lLastTime;
                long lPassCount = 0;
                long lSumOfPassTimesInMilliSecs = 0;
                long lTimeDiff = 0l;

                while (! bFrameIsOpen) {
                    try {
                        sleep(iFiftyMSecs);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JPanelLiteBrixFlicker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } // while (! bFrameIsOpen)

                boolean bIsEven = true;

                lLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                lCurrentTime = lLastTime;

                while (bFrameIsOpen && lPassCount < 1000) {

// I'm varying iAlzheimersFrequency between 12 <-> 13Hz on every pass to more closely
// approximate 12.5ms. 1 Hz equals two passes in the code below.

                    if (bIsEven) {
                        iAlzheimersFrequency ++;
                        oJButton.setBackground(cMagenta);
                        oJButton.setForeground(cWhite);
                    }
                    else {
                        iAlzheimersFrequency --;
                        oJButton.setBackground(cWhite);
                        oJButton.setForeground(cMagenta);
                    }

                    oJButton.repaint();

                    bIsEven =! bIsEven;

                    lCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    lTimeDiff = lCurrentTime - lLastTime;
                    lLastTime = lCurrentTime;

                    if (lTimeDiff > iAlzheimersFrequency) {
                        if (iCurrentThreadPriority < Thread.MAX_PRIORITY)
                            setPriority(iCurrentThreadPriority ++);
                        lDelayTimeInMilliSecs --;
                        bIsIncreasing = false;
                    }  // end if (lTimeDiff > iAlzheimersFrequency)
                    else {
                        lDelayTimeInMilliSecs ++;
                        bIsIncreasing = true;
                        if (iCurrentThreadPriority > Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
                            setPriority(iCurrentThreadPriority --);
                    }  // else

//                        boolean b = (((int) lPassCount % 10) == 0);
//                        if (b)
//                            System.out.println("lPassCount: " + lPassCount + ", iCurrentThreadPriority: " + iCurrentThreadPriority);
//                        else
//                            System.out.println("\tlPassCount: " + lPassCount + ", iCurrentThreadPriority: " + iCurrentThreadPriority);

                    lSumOfPassTimesInMilliSecs += lTimeDiff;
                    lPassCount ++;

                    if (lDelayTimeInMilliSecs <= 0)
                        lDelayTimeInMilliSecs = 1;

                    oLinkedListOfStatsElements.add(new StatsElement(lPassCount, bIsIncreasing, 
                      iCurrentThreadPriority, lTimeDiff));

                    try {
                        sleep(lDelayTimeInMilliSecs);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(JPanelLiteBrixFlicker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }  // end while (bFrameIsOpen)

                accrueNPrintStats(oLinkedListOfStatsElements, lPassCount, lSumOfPassTimesInMilliSecs);

            }  // end run()
        }.start();
    }

    public void setFrameIsOpen(boolean bFrameIsOpen) {
        this.bFrameIsOpen = bFrameIsOpen;
    }

    private void accrueNPrintStats(LinkedList<StatsElement> oLinkedListOfStatsElements, long lPassCount, 
      long lSumOfPassTimesInMilliSecs) {

        long lCurrentThreadPriority = 0l;
        long lIsIncreasing = 0l;
        long lTimeDiff = 0l;

        StatsElement oStatsElement;

        for (long oL = 0; oL < oLinkedListOfStatsElements.size(); oL ++) {
            oStatsElement = oLinkedListOfStatsElements.get((int) oL);

            lCurrentThreadPriority += oStatsElement.getCurrentThreadPriority();

            if (oStatsElement.getIsIncreasing())
                lIsIncreasing += 1;

            lTimeDiff += oStatsElement.getTimeDiff();
        }

        System.out.println("In iAccrueNPrintStatsCount(), lPassCount Is: " + lPassCount + 
          ", AvgCurrentThreadPriority: " + ((float) lCurrentThreadPriority / (float) lPassCount) + 
          ", AvgSumOfPassTimeInMSec: " + ((float) lSumOfPassTimesInMilliSecs / (float) lPassCount) + 
          ", AvgIsIncreasing: " + ((float) lIsIncreasing / (float) lPassCount));

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 255), null));
        setFont(new java.awt.Font("Liberation Sans", 1, 16)); // NOI18N
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 60));
        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                onMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void onMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_onMouseClicked
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_onMouseClicked

    private void configureButton() {
        oJButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            bFrameIsOpen =! bFrameIsOpen;
        });

        oJButton.setBorder(new RoundedBorder(20));
        oJButton.setBounds(20, 20, 30, 30);
        oJButton.setBackground(new Color(242, 242, 242));
        oJButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        oJButton.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
        oJButton.setOpaque(true);

        add(oJButton);
    }

    public void setFrameOpen(boolean bFrameIsOpen) {
        this.bFrameIsOpen = bFrameIsOpen;
    }

    private class StatsElement {
        boolean bIsIncreasing;

        int iCurrentThreadPriority;
        long lPassCount;
        long lTimeDiff;

        private StatsElement(long lPassCount, boolean bIsIncreasing, int iCurrentThreadPriority, long lTimeDiff) {

            this.bIsIncreasing = bIsIncreasing;
            this.iCurrentThreadPriority = iCurrentThreadPriority;
            this.lPassCount = lPassCount;
            this.lTimeDiff = lTimeDiff;

        }

        private int getCurrentThreadPriority() {
            return (iCurrentThreadPriority);
        }

        private boolean getIsIncreasing() {
            return bIsIncreasing;
        }

        private long getPassCount() {
            return lPassCount;
        }

        private long getTimeDiff() {
            return lTimeDiff;
        }

    }

    /*
     * Simple Runnable implementation
     */
    private class Task implements Runnable {
        private final String caller;
       
        public Task(String caller){
            this.caller = caller;
        }
       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + getName() + " running run() #2.");
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

My results are as follows:

In iAccrueNPrintStatsCount(), lPassCount Is: 1000, AvgCurrentThreadPriority: 6.609, AvgSumOfPassTimeInMSec: 13.083, AvgIsIncreasing: 0.498.

Synopsis:

To determine that the loop inside the thread is flipping the jbutton at the speed that I wanted to hit 40Hz, I added code that shows that indeed it is.

I was expecting the jbutton would flicker at 40Hz, but it was only flickering a few times a second.